# Socket.io + React: Different classes -> use same socket?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

This is hopefully my best take at describing and simplifying my problem:

I have my main class for my react app called App  in App.js (I use [...] as Placeholder for other code):

```
import {myComponent} from "./components.js";

const { io } = require("socket.io-client");

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isLoaded
         [...]
         }
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket = io()
        [...]
        }
    render() {
       const {isLoaded, [...]} = this.state
       return (
         <h1>BLUB</h1>
         <myComponent/>
         [...]
         )
       }
  }
```

myComponent is defined in components.js and imported into App.js. I have also implemeted socket.io following the instructions in their documentation. As you see on componentDidMount() I define this.socket for the communication to the server. **My question is how can I tell myComponent to use this specific socket as well, eventough it is located in components.js?**

```
class myComponent extends Component {
 ???
}

 export {myComponent}
```

Thanks for every piece of advice :)

PS: I moved myComponent out of App.js and the class App, to reduce the class size, it was getting out of control...